# Loop through hashtags in string and insert to database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working on a project where I am trying to get the hashtags from posts when a user submits it. Then I put the matches into a database for reference. My question is, is there a more efficient way to do this? My current code is running way too many queries resulting in slow post time.

The code loops through each tag and checks if it exists in the database if it does it just add an item referencing the tag with the post if it doesn't exist it adds the tag to the database and adds the reference of the tag and the post.

I tried this but don't know where I could improve it with the same function

```
foreach($hashtags as $tag){
  if(DB::query('SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag=:tag', array(':tag' => $tag))){
    $tag = DB::query('SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag=:tag', array(':tag' => $tag))[0];
    DB::query ( "INSERT INTO post_tags VALUES(:tagid, :postid)", array (':tagid' => $tag['id'], ':postid' => $postid) );
  }else{
    $id = hash(sha256, $tag);
    DB::query ( "INSERT INTO tags VALUES(:id, :tag, :mode)", array (':id' => $id, ':tag' => $tag, ':mode' => 0) );
    DB::query ( "INSERT INTO post_tags VALUES(:tagid, :postid)", array (':tagid' => $id, ':postid' => $postid) );
  }
}
```

Comment: how slow it is?

Comment: @Wils The thing is it can depend on the amount of tags. Posts can have from one tag to multiple which would slow it.

Comment: how slow is slow? 10 seconds?

Answer (score 2):

Don't compare your tags directly in the query. I would suggest to get all tags in an array and then check using `in_array` function. It will be faster.

If you want to go with the query comparison then add an index to the tag column so it will make your comparison faster.

Explanation: (Brief)

1. Get all the tags into php array by querying the table. For this, the query should be without any conditions, e.g.

   ```
   $tag = DB::query('SELECT * FROM tags')[0];
   ```
2. Convert the query result into an array if not and store it to the same array, e.g.

   ```
   $tag = $tag->toArray();
   ```
3. Then loop through the input array tag to check if they are present:

   ```
   $filteredArray = array();
   $newTags = array();

   foreach($hashtags as $t) {
       if(in_array($t, $tag))
       {
           $filteredArray[] = $t;
       }
       else {
           $newTags[] = $t;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Then insert the matching tags into db using insert query.

   ```
   if(!empty($allTags)) {
       $allTags = array_column($t,'id');
       DB::query ( "INSERT INTO post_tags VALUES(:tagid, :postid)", array (':tagid' => $allTags, ':postid' => $postid) );
   }
   else
   {
        // Otherwise get all the new tags and then insert them along with mode = 0 and create `post_tags` too.
   }
   ```

**NOTE:** This is a totally brief idea. You should correct the conditions and set it properly.

Comment: Could you explain it a little more please?